# Why are @complete shortcuts not working inside class definition?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm starting to learn kotlin, by reading the "Kotlin big nerd ranch guide" from 2018 (I know is a little old and I accept suggestions for newer/better books if you have any, although I think this one is pretty good; back to the problem description).

I've got this problem where I've got to move outside the class definition in a newly created kotlin class, in intelliJ IDEA, to be able to use autocomplete for the main function, for example, and probably in many other cases, that's why I'm worried about this. I'm all about learning to be productive when I'm starting to use a new IDE.

```
/*If the caret is here and I type "main" and then press TAB, the IDE replaces
  the word with "fun main(...) {...}", as it's defined in my settings (Keymap), I can
  also use ctrl+shift+intro and the IDE also replaces the main word with the text 
  I just pasted.*/
class NyetHack {
    /*If the caret is here, and I want to type "main" and then press TAB, 
      or ctrl+shift+intro, it just doesn't seem to recognize the "main" word, 
      the IDE seems to believe I'm trying to autocomplete something it can't.*/
}
```

I'm using intelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1 community edition.

- why is this happening?
- can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attached a screenshot it would have been more clear what you do and when happens but I think you are talking about the [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) completion.

Each **Live Template** snippet has a [**context**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-live-templates.html#context_menu) where it is applicable: the context could be a *class*, *comment*, *statement*, *expression* etc. The `main` is available on the source file **Top Level** context:

[image]

Comment: I knew it had something to do with the context, didn't face the situation I described in the question using any other IDE though. I checked my settings in windows and couldn't find the context by myself nor the live templates tab. I'll try it when I get home. Thanks.